# How to include JSPs into others that have servlet mapping to change the URL?

Tags: java, servlets, web.xml, servlet-mapping

I have a main file (main.jsp) which includes multiple other JSPs.

I've added some servlet mapping to main.jsp to change the url from:

```
folder/appname/main.jsp
```

to:

```
appname/
```

Here is my web.xml:

```
<servlet>
    <servlet-name>Main</servlet-name>
    <jsp-file>/folder/appname/main.jsp</jsp-file>
</servlet>
<servlet-mapping>
    <servlet-name>Main</servlet-name>
    <url-pattern>/appname/</url-pattern>
</servlet-mapping>
```

The problem however, is that when I load this page i get the following error

```
java.io.FileNotFoundException: /page_modules/included_file.jsp
```

The file above is included in the main.jsp like so:

```
<jsp:include page="page_modules/included_file.jsp" />
```

Folder structure as requested:

```
Dynamic Web Project
    >Java Resources
        >src
            >com.project
                >servlet
    >WebContent
        >forms
            >folder
                main.jsp
                >page_modules
                    included_file.jsp
```

Comment: Can you give a screenshot of your project structure? And post your jsp page where you trying to include

Comment: @AvijitBarua I have added the folder structure as an edit to the original question.

Comment: Can you check my answer?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Try using code like

```
<jsp:include page="/page_modules/included_file.jsp" />
```

Or

```
<jsp:include page="/forms/folder/page_modules/included_file.jsp" />
```

Comment: This is 90% correct, thank you. For anyone wondering in the future, as 'WebContent' is the root, I used page="/forms/folder/page_modules' etc.